# Console application freezes until key pressed / mouse clicked

Tags: console-application

Sometimes it works great, but usually after i started application (after log)- nothing happen. **Just after i press key**- consumers start to work (that's not displaying problem, because there are messages in queues and they are not going to be free before i press keyboard key).

[image]

At this demonstration i started current service. It took some messages and went to sleep. After that i sent more messages (using Web API application), but nothing happen in service. Just after i pressed key in service console window it woke up.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I've just unchecked the `Property > Options > Edit Options > QuickEdit Mode` checkbox.

[image]

Possible duplicate answer: [How and why does QuickEdit mode in Command Prompt freeze applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30418886/2524304)

Comment: It's hard to understand what you clicked since it's in Russian.  Can you type out your solution here to help others who encounter this?

Comment: @qodeninja Done!