# How to detect Console application freeze on mouse click

Tags: c#, console-application

I have a simple WCF-Service that I run in the console when testing it. Sometime I want to have the console windows on top of the other windows so I click it. This activates the "Mark and Paste" command and then freezes the whole application  (service becomes unresponsive) until I press enter.

I find that rather annoying.

I don't want to disable the "Mark and Paste", because sometimes I copy text from the console.

**Is there any way to detect that the application is frozen?**

If I knew when this was the case, I could maybe change the windows titel to display a warning.

EDIT:
This is not a duplicate, because I want to know how to handle the freeze and not why it feels frozen. I know now that only the writing to the output is frozen, which causes my application to feel like it is frozen.

Comment: A *frozen* application can't detect anything. If you want to copy text you'll have to log it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How and why does QuickEdit mode in Command Prompt freeze applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30418886/how-and-why-does-quickedit-mode-in-command-prompt-freeze-applications)

Comment: @RvdK if, as the duplicate suggests, the only thing that freezes is the *console* a logging library that logs messages in the background, or even one that uses buffering, wouldn't be affected

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: It only feels frozen, but it is not actually frozen. Sorry for the confusion, I am reaching the limit of my english capabilities here. Feel free to edit to make is clearer.

Comment: It is a feature, not a bug.  Not otherwise different from the kind of freeze you'd get when you press Ctrl+S.  At least configure your console so it is not so easy to trigger it by accident, press Alt+Space > Properties > Options tab > untick "QuickEdit mode".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As explained [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30517482), in this mode terminal just stops reading from your application output, which causes your writes to that output (such as `Console.WriteLine(...)`) to hang.

If you control code that writes to console, you can achieve your goal (change console title when "freeze" is detected) like this:

```
static async Task WriteLine(string text) {            
    var delay = Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
    var writeTask = Task.Run(() => Console.WriteLine(text));
    var oldTitle = Console.Title;
    if (await Task.WhenAny(delay, writeTask) == delay) {
        // after one second Console.WriteLine still did not return
        // we are probably in "mark and paste" mode
        Console.Title = "FREEZED!";
    }
    // we cannot ignore our write, have to wait anyway
    await writeTask;
    Console.Title = oldTitle;
}
```

And using this method instead of regular `Console.WriteLine`. Of course this is of limited usage, but I think it answers your question.

You can test it with simple:

```
static async Task Main(string[] args) {
    while (true) {
        await WriteLine("test");
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

and observe that console title will change to FREEZED! while you are in that mode, and will change back when you are out of it.

Comment: I like that a lot, thank you! I will give it a try. The only but: I think in your solution, if the is a lot of stuff written to the console, the order is no longer guaranteed.

Comment: @flayn this code is sequential, so order is guaranteed (provided that you always do `await WriteLine("...")`). While it uses `Task.Run` - there is nothing parallel here (note that in the end, `Console.WriteLine` is always awaited with `await writeTask`).