# PowerShell Script Wont Start (randomly)

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

I have a frequent random problem using VSCode to write and run PowerShell scripts on my Windows 10 VM.
When I press F5 on the keyboard, it acts like it is going to start running the script, but it doesn't. Sometimes, the status bar goes orange like it's going to run, but nothing else happens, and sometimes the bar stays blue.  The debug icon on the left has a "wait clock" like it's waiting for something, but nothing happens. I get the run/debug toolbar at the top every time. Often to work around this, I have to stop and start multiple times until it finally goes.  I also have to press "enter" in the terminal sometimes to get it unstuck.  And sometimes I have to quit VSCode completely for it to get unstuck.

I am not sure where to look in VSCode to find out what is holding it up, but I would appreciate guidance, as I haven't found anyone else with this problem at this time.  Thanks.

Comment: Looks like you have multiple problems here... Concerning the "Press ENTER thing": You probably clicked accidentally into the terminal and entered the selection mode, which pauses the execution. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61538154/11942268) for a similar problem.

Comment: Thank you, but no, I did not accidentally click within the terminal to pause execution.