# Problem with python code stopping without reason

Tags: python, algorithm, csv, execution

I have a problem with a Python code when going through large CSV files.

Basically, the code inputs a CSV file and outputs another CSV file with some math calculations. The input file is really big (about 300,000 rows). The problem is that when I run the code, Python will automatically stop after a while. When I press Ctrl+C, the code starts running again. (The code takes about 7 minutes to run)

I am sure there is nothing wrong is the code, because when the CSV file is made smaller, the code runs properly. This problem only occurs when the file is large. Pressing Ctrl+C a few times throughout execution will produce the output file correctly. There is also no Error message throughout.

Although the file is big, it isn't big enough such that Python can't handle it. I am using Windows 10, Python 3.7.1, my computer RAM is 16GB. The CPU and Memory usage do not reach max when running the code.

```
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    import black_scholes as bs
    from datetime import date
    import time
    import glob

    t0 = time.time()

    ## Initiate all the steps
    def start():

        global df,bs_list,errors
        global r

        files = glob.glob('./*.csv')
        print(files)
        for name in files:

            t0 = time.time()

            df = open_file(name[2:])

            print(name[2:])

            #df['DTE'] = df.apply(calc.time, axis=1)
            df['DTE'] = np.vectorize(calc.dte)(df['DataDate'],df['Expiration'])
            print('DTE column ... done')

            r = calc.fed_rate(df.loc[10]['DataDate'][:10])
            print('R calc ... done')

            bs_list,errors = [],[]
            #df['IV'] = df.apply(add.iv,axis=1)
            df['IV'] = np.vectorize(add.iv)                (df['Bid'],df['Ask'],df['Strike'],df['UnderlyingPrice'],df['DTE'],df['Type'])
            print('IV calc ... done')

            df['Delta'],df['Gamma'],df['Theta'],df['Vega'] = np.vectorize(add.greeks)(df['IV'],df['Bid'],df['Ask'],df['Strike'],df['UnderlyingPrice'],df['DTE'],df['Type'])

            create_file(name[2:-4]+'_edited.csv',df)
            print(name[2:-4]+'_edited.csv'+' ... Addition successful')

            t1 = time.time()
            total = t1-t0
            print(total)

    ## Open .csv file using pandas
    def open_file(filename):

        df = pd.read_csv(filename)
        df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(' ', '')
        return df

    def create_file(filename,df):

        df.to_csv(filename, encoding='utf-8', index=False)

    class calc:

        ## Calculate the DTE of all options
        def dte(DataDate,Expiration):

            start,end = DataDate[:10],Expiration
            start,end = start.split('/'),end.split('/')

            d0 = date(int(start[2]),int(start[0]),int(start[1]))
            d1 = date(int(end[2]),int(end[0]),int(end[1]))
            delta = d1 - d0

            return delta.days

        ## Finds the risk-free interest rate of that day
        def fed_rate(date):

            file = pd.read_csv('fed_rate.csv')
            date = date.split('/')
            date[0] = date[0].replace('0','')
            date[1] = date[1].replace('0','')

            for index, row in file.iterrows():
                fed_date = row['THE_DATE']
                fed_date = fed_date.split('/')
                if fed_date[2] == date[2] and fed_date[0] == date[0]:
                    return row['FEDFUNDS']

    class add:

        ## Calculate IV of each option
        def iv(bid,ask,strike,price,dte,c_p):

            try:
                bid,ask,strike,price,dte = float(bid),float(ask),float(strike),float(price),float(dte)

                if bid <= 0.1:
                    return 0
                elif ask <= 0.1:
                    return 0
                option_price = (bid+ask)/2

                bs_list.append([price,dte/365,strike,r/100,option_price,0])
                print(len(bs_list))
                if len(bs_list) == 100064 or len(bs_list) == 100065:
                    print(bs_list[-1])

                if c_p == 'call':
                    iv = bs.call.vol(price,dte/365,strike,r/100,option_price,0)
                elif c_p == 'put':
                    iv = bs.put.vol(price,dte/365,strike,r/100,option_price,0)
            except:
                try:
                    errors.append(['iv',price,dte/365,strike,r/100,option_price,0])
                except:
                    pass
                return 0

    return iv

## Add Greeks to file
        def greeks(iv,bid,ask,strike,price,dte,c_p):

            if iv == 0:
                return 0,0,0,0

            try:
                ## Delta
                if c_p == 'call':
                    delta = bs.greeks.delta(float(price),dte/365,float(strike),r/100,iv,0,'c')
                elif c_p == 'put':
                    delta = bs.greeks.delta(float(price),dte/365,float(strike),r/100,iv,0,'p')

                ## Gamma
                gamma = bs.greeks.gamma(float(price),dte/365,float(strike),r/100,iv,0)

                ## Theta
                if c_p == 'call':
                    theta = bs.greeks.theta(float(price),dte/365,float(strike),r/100,iv,0,'c')
                elif c_p == 'put':
                    theta = bs.greeks.theta(float(price),dte/365,float(strike),r/100,iv,0,'p')

                ## Vega
                vega = bs.greeks.vega(float(price),dte/365,float(strike),r/100,iv,0)
            except:
        errors.append(['greeks',float(price),dte/365,float(strike),r/100,iv,0])
                return 0

            return delta,gamma,theta,vega
```

Any idea what kind of problem is this? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I mean, if you want people to take a guess at the issue, you really need to provide something.

Comment: I think the code would be useful still

Comment: How long does it takes to make all this calculations??

Comment: Just gonna throw it out there that I’ve never experienced this on Linux ;) seriously though if I don’t see any code I don’t know how I’d answer this bud. Could very well be something you’re looking over.

Comment: I just added the code

Comment: Are you using powershell?

Comment: @MattMessersmith No. I am using Python IDLE

Comment: Try adding time.sleep(0.1) in between the major steps of your algorithm

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes Windows seems to stop the program execution of long running programs to let other tasks run. I've encountered similar things in C++ a while ago (also on Windows 10), so this seems to be just Windows behaviour.

Similar behaviour was spotted [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-performance/windows-10-processes-becoming-suspended/bd577393-efb8-4a3b-9d44-35fe1612cb1b).

Comment: Is there a way to prevent Windows from doing this? The frequent pauses are frustrating.

Comment: None that I know of. Maybe reall just restart your computer, this will empty all caches and maybe it stops if the cache isn't saturated. But no guarantees.

Comment: I've never encountered this problem when running programs in Python. Recently I executed a program that lasted about 5 hours straight and never found that windows did that.

Comment: I have personally run python code that ran for 3 days and not faced this issue. I am not saying if it can or can't happen, but i do not think Windows should be blamed this quickly here.

Comment: I never encountered this problem with Windows 10 (older relases like 7). I do encountered programms that were terminated due to violations like memory leaks, with show only after some hours or days of execution. @ThomasLang can you provide a documentation of this behavior?

Comment: @BrunoRanieri Apparently not, I just encountered some very similar behaviour but only on Windows. I'm still searching for known cases, but no luck yet. However, I did notice that this behaviour disappeared after the latest update.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Windows, you have to be mindful of "Quick Edit Mode". This makes it so that your terminal will "pause" if you click it. You can resume with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> or any key for the matter.

You can turn it off by right clicking the top bar of your shell (works both for cmd and powershell), then go to properties, and uncheck "Quick Edit Mode". It would be nice if it were *off* by default, as it's a feature that can drive one to the brink of insanity if they're caught unawares.

This may or may not be your issue, as systems issues like these are obviously not reproducible, so I can't verify.

HTH though, either you or the next victim of "Quick Edit Mode".

More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30418886/how-and-why-does-quickedit-mode-in-command-prompt-freeze-applications).

Comment: But I am using Python IDLE, not Command Prompt. Also, the problem still exists if I change the "Quick Edit Mode" and run using Command Prompt.