# SDL2: Calling cout after Clicking console window causes Freeze

Tags: c++, windows, sdl-2

Using SDL2.  If I test run in Visual Studio (with Subsystem:Console, so the console will show too) then click the console window, then click back into the SDL window, and call a cout within the SDL_PollEvent loop, the program freezes.

e.g.

```
if (ev.type == SDL_KEYDOWN)
{
    if (ev.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_SPACE)
    {
        //causes an immediate freeze
        std::cout << "space pressed" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

It can be another sort of event, such as an SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN event, but it seems that clicking the console window, then returning to the main SDL window, then calling cout, triggers this somehow.  Clicking another window, such as Visual Studio, does not cause this to happen.

Would anyone know why this is happening, and how I can alleviate this issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How and why does QuickEdit mode in Command Prompt freeze applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30418886/how-and-why-does-quickedit-mode-in-command-prompt-freeze-applications)